# "NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined" with datetime imported

Tags: python-3.x

I know there are a lot of `datetime` not defined posts but they all seem to forget the obvious import of `datetime`. I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. When I do each step in iPython it works well, but the method dosen't

```
import requests
import datetime

def daily_price_historical(symbol, comparison_symbol, limit=1, aggregate=1, exchange='', allData='true'):

    url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym={}&tsym={}&limit={}&aggregate={}&allData={}'\
        .format(symbol.upper(), comparison_symbol.upper(), limit, aggregate, allData)
    if exchange:
        url += '&e={}'.format(exchange)
    page = requests.get(url)
    data = page.json()['Data']
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['timestamp'] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d) for d in df.time]

    datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()

    return df
```

This code produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\20115619\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-29-4f015e05113f>", line 1, in <module>
    rv.get_prices(30, 'ETH')
  File "C:\Users\20115619\Desktop\projects\testDash\Revas.py", line 161, in get_prices
    for symbol in symbols:
  File "C:\Users\20115619\Desktop\projects\testDash\Revas.py", line 50, in daily_price_historical
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  File "C:\Users\20115619\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4372, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'time'
```

Comment: Your error message in the question does not match the one in the question's title, please correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df['timestamp'] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d) for d in df.time]`

I think that line is the problem.

Your Dataframe `df` at the end of the line doesn't have the attribute `.time`

For what it's worth I'm on `Python 3.6.0` and this runs perfectly for me:

```
import requests
import datetime
import pandas as pd

def daily_price_historical(symbol, comparison_symbol, limit=1, aggregate=1, exchange='', allData='true'):
    url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym={}&tsym={}&limit={}&aggregate={}&allData={}'\
        .format(symbol.upper(), comparison_symbol.upper(), limit, aggregate, allData)
    if exchange:
        url += '&e={}'.format(exchange)
    page = requests.get(url)
    data = page.json()['Data']
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['timestamp'] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d) for d in df.time]
    #I don't have the following function, but it's not needed to run this
    #datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()
    return df

df = daily_price_historical('BTC', 'ETH')
print(df)
```

Note, I commented out the line that calls an external function that I do not have.  Perhaps you have a global variable causing a problem?

**Update** as per the comments:

I'd use `join` instead to make the URL:

`url = "".join(["https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=", str(symbol.upper()), "&tsym=", str(comparison_symbol.upper()), "&limit=", str(limit), "&aggregate=", str(aggregate), "&allData=", str(allData)])`

Comment: yes i know its this line. the dataframe has a column named time. im trying to convert from a unix time stamp. like i said, it works in a ipython, why wont it work in my program

Comment: Can you rename the `time` column in the dataframe?  Perhaps it's conflicting with the `.time` from datetime?  It really looks like the `df` doesn't have a time column from the error.

Comment: you are right i added a print(df.head()) before the line in question and the df is empty, but in ipython it isnt. this is weird. thanks for the help. ill go for a walk and figure it out

Comment: if figured out whats the problem just not sure why its happening. the {} are supposed to put the arguments into the url string but only the char from the symbol variable is being added to the url. any ideas?

Comment: @AaronFoster I'd use `join` instead to make the URL: `url = "".join(["https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=", str(symbol.upper()), "&tsym=", str(comparison_symbol.upper()), "&limit=", str(limit), "&aggregate=", str(aggregate), "&allData=", str(allData)])`  If that ends up working, I'll update the answer with it.